# Can't update LDAP module due to Memory Limit

Tags: 7, updating, debugging

I need to update the LDAP module from 7.1.x to 7.2.x to remove a fatal error. When I navigate to the update.php script, there are 18 updates. When I run the script I get this error:

```
An AJAX HTTP error occurred. HTTP Result Code: 200 Debugging information follows. Path: https://www-dev.site.com/mysite/update.php?op=selection&token=Ct2z9U8FEbzMqkjyvubbvaL_WxETSh-8xy_r7FqAzgE&id=5164&op=do 
StatusText: OK ResponseText: Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 523800 bytes) in
/var/www/webaccounts/mysite/public_html/sites/all/modules/ldap/ldap_servers/ldap_servers.install on line 290
```

It started at 128 mb, then I increased it in double increments to try and solve the problem but there is no change, even at 1024 mb. This doesn't seem to be a memory issue. What is causing the problem?

Comment: Are you trying to update all 18 at once, or one at a time?

Comment: What is the name of the update hook that is failing?

Comment: I am simply navigating to mysite.com/update.php and clicking the update button. I think I will close this issue; the ldap module has no upgrade path from 7.1 to 7.2.